# Syntax for gdb python pretty printers to print a single element of a vector

Tags: c++, stl, gdb, pretty-print

Is there a way to directly print an element of a vector as there was with the old pretty printer macros. I have vectors with 100,000 of entries and I do not want to page through all that output when I know the index of the element I wish

The old way used to be like this

```
pv Vector 10500
```

Would print element 10500.

I've tried latest revision `revision 187855` from SVN and no joy.

Apart from using the macros written by Dan Marinescu - is there a way to do this with the python ones (without writing my own)

Answer (score 0):

if the operator[] is compiled in you should be able to:

```
p Vector[10500]
```

otherwise i'm not sure.

Comment: Doesn't work in a non running process :-(. Core was taken with gcore - so its just static snapshot - cannot execute any code.